# How to create the conditions on the model of eloquent? (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

My delete method on the controller is like this :

```
<?php
public function deleteMessage($id, $seller_id, $buyer_id)
{
    //if the seller delete
    if($seller_id == auth()->user->id)
        //const DELETED_AT = 'deleted_by_seller';
    //if the buyer delete
    else($buyer_id == auth()->user->id)
        //const DELETED_AT = 'deleted_by_buyer';

    $result = Message::destroy($id);
    return $result;
}
```

My model is like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent; 
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\HybridRelations;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class MessageThread extends Eloquent
{
    use HybridRelations; 
    use SoftDeletes; 
    // const DELETED_AT = 'deleted_by_seller';
    // const DELETED_AT = 'deleted_by_buyer';
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_by_seller', 'deleted_by_buyer'];
    protected  $fillable = ['subject', 'information', 'created_at', 'update_at'];
}
```

I wanted to like this :

if the seller delete the message then : `const DELETED_AT = 'deleted_by_seller';`

if the buyer delete the message then : `const DELETED_AT = 'deleted_by_buyer';`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I would suggest it's not an ideal DB structure that you have. You should have two columns: deleted_by and deleted_at instead of including deleted_by_seller and deleted_by_buyer with one of them null all the time.

If you still want to go ahead with your existing DB structure, as @William pointed out, try this:

In your model class, add the following:

```
 protected $deletedAtCol = "deleted_at";

 /**
 * Get the name of the "deleted at" column.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDeletedAtColumn()
{
    return $this->deletedAtCol;
}

/**
 * Set the name of the "deleted at" column.
 * @param string $colName
 * @return string
 */
public function setDeletedAtColumn($colName)
{
    $this->deletedAtCol = $colName;
}
```

Then in your controller, add this:

```
public function deleteMessage($id, $seller_id, $buyer_id)
{
    $message = Message::findOrFail($id); 
    //if the seller delete
    if($seller_id == auth()->user->id)
        $message->setDeletedAtCol("deleted_by_seller");
    //if the buyer delete
    else($buyer_id == auth()->user->id)
        $message->setDeletedAtCol("deleted_by_buyer");

    return $message->delete();
}
```

Comment: If I use your way, that is using two columns: deleted_by and deleted_at. How can I fill deleted_by? If deleted_at then it is already automatically filled

Comment: For that method, you can use model events: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events

Comment: Just add a `deleting` Eloquent event for the message model and add something like `$message->deleted_by = auth()->user()->id`

Comment: I try this : `$message = message::findOrFail($id); 
$message->deleted_by = auth()->user()->id;
return $message->delete();`. It does not work

Comment: Try saving the message before deleting

Comment: `$message = Message::findOrFail($id); 
$message->deleted_by = auth()->user()->id;
$message->save();
return $message->delete();`. It works

Answer (score 4):

Update:

> the original article refers my [personal blog](//www.xiaolewei.com)

## SoftDeletes Trait

In laravel, we define our own model by extending `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`. To delete a model instance softly, we should use `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes` trait in our model. `runSoftDelete()` is the key function in `SoftDeletes` trait building a sql query, getting the column which is used to mark whether the record has been deleted or not and then update the column with current timestamps.

```
protected function runSoftDelete()
{
    $query = $this->newQueryWithoutScopes()->where($this->getKeyName(), $this->getKey());
    $this->{$this->getDeletedAtColumn()} = $time = $this->freshTimestamp();
    $query->update([$this->getDeletedAtColumn() => $this->fromDateTime($time)]);
}
```

## Procedure of Delete()

What happens when we call `delete()` function on a model?

Since our own model extends the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, we take a glance at it. Here is the `delete()` function:

```
public function delete()
{
    if (is_null($this->getKeyName())) {
        throw new Exception('No primary key defined on model.');
    }

    if ($this->exists) {
        if ($this->fireModelEvent('deleting') === false) {
            return false;
        }

        // Here, we'll touch the owning models, verifying these timestamps get updated
        // for the models. This will allow any caching to get broken on the parents
        // by the timestamp. Then we will go ahead and delete the model instance.
        $this->touchOwners();

        $this->performDeleteOnModel();

        $this->exists = false;

        // Once the model has been deleted, we will fire off the deleted event so that
        // the developers may hook into post-delete operations. We will then return
        // a boolean true as the delete is presumably successful on the database.
        $this->fireModelEvent('deleted', false);

        return true;
    }
}
```

The code is clear. It ensures the model has a `primaryKey` and the instance exists in database firstly. Then call `performDeleteOnModel()` function to perform deletion opreation. Attention should be paid!

Here we should know:

> An inherited member from a base class is overridden by a member inserted by a Trait. The precedence order is that members from the current class override Trait methods, which in turn override inherited methods.

So the exact function executes when `performDeleteOnModel()` called is the one with the same name in `SoftDeletes` trait but not the one in `Model` class. And now we turn back to the trait:

```
protected function performDeleteOnModel()
{
    if ($this->forceDeleting) {
        return $this->newQueryWithoutScopes()->where($this->getKeyName(), $this->getKey())->forceDelete();
    }

    return $this->runSoftDelete();
}
```

Well, it calls `runSoftDelete()` we have talked about in the beginning. And this is procedure of soft detetion.

## Problems on Getting

The asker wants to use different `DELETED_AT` columns when deleting. It leaves much to be desired to keep soft deletion mechanism working well by overridding `getDeletedAtColumn()` only. Why the deleted models are still in results even if they have been deleted softly?

When `Model` class is constructed, it will boot traits by calling their their `boot[TraitName]` method. Thus here is `bootSoftDelete()` method.

```
protected static function bootTraits()
{
    foreach (class_uses_recursive(get_called_class()) as $trait) {
        if (method_exists(get_called_class(), $method = 'boot'.class_basename($trait))) {
            forward_static_call([get_called_class(), $method]);
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's pour attention on the `SoftDeletes` trait again.

```
public static function bootSoftDeletes()
{
    static::addGlobalScope(new SoftDeletingScope);
}
```

Here the trait registers a `SoftDeletingScope` class having an `apply()` method by calling `static::addGlobalScope()`. The method, which located in `Model` class stores it into `$globalScopes` array.

```
public static function addGlobalScope(ScopeInterface $scope)
{
    static::$globalScopes[get_called_class()][get_class($scope)] = $scope;
}
```

When a query is built on a model, `applyGlobalScopes()` method will be called automatically, visiting instances in `$globalScopes` array one by one and call their `apply()` method.

```
public function applyGlobalScopes($builder)
{
    foreach ($this->getGlobalScopes() as $scope) {
        $scope->apply($builder, $this);
    }

    return $builder;
}
```

We will lift the veil of problem now. In `SoftDeletingScope` class:

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
{
    $builder->whereNull($model->getQualifiedDeletedAtColumn());

    $this->extend($builder);
}
```

It will add a constraint on every query to select those records whose `DELETED_AT` column is null. And this is the secret of `SoftDeletes`.

## Dynamic DELETED_AT Column

Firstly, I need to reaffirm that I don't recommend such behaviour of using dynamic `DELETED_AT` column.

In order to solve the asker's problems of dynamic `DELETED_AT` column, you need to implement your own `SoftDeletingScope` class with such `apply()` function:

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
{
    $builder->where(function ($query){
        $query->where('DELETED_AT_COLUMN_1',null)->orWhere('DELETED_AT_COLUMN_2',null);
    });

    $this->extend($builder);
}
```

And then overide `bootSoftDeletes()` with it

```
public static function bootSoftDeletes()
{
    static::addGlobalScope(new YourOwnSoftDeletingScope);
}
```

Original answer:

You can't change the value of a `const` variable in the running time. So you need to assign the value of `CREATED_AT` manually.

Comment: Does that mean for my case there is no solution? Because I need to change it based on certain conditions

Comment: If you insist on dong so.  You can override the `getDeletedAtColumn` method in your model. Every time, you destroy your model, the `SoftDeletes ` will call this method to get the column which need to be modify.

Comment: `getDeletedAtColumn` is used at what time. The code that is described by @Paras, the unused

Comment: well, it's a big topic. You can check the content of `SoftDeletes` trait which locates `XXX/vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Database/Eloquent/SoftDeletes.php`.

Comment: So `getDeletedAtColumn` function called from there. I am still confused. Because when I do a delete, deleted_by_seller has the value date. But when I run a listing of data, The data is still showing. If using deleted_at it does not appear